# cat Input/output error when copying ROM file

Tags: cat

I was following [this guide](https://github.com/QaidVoid/Complete-Single-GPU-Passthrough#enable--verify-iommu) on how to do single gpu passthrough, I reached the **vBIOS Patching** section and ran this code:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/rom
sudo cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/rom > path/to/dump/vbios.rom
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/rom
```

Got an `Input/Output error` so I tried to run it in recovery mode and still got the same output:
[image]

```
root@wanka-GL703VM:~# echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/rom
1
root@wanka-GL703VM:~# sudo cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/rom > /home/wanka/vbios.rom
cat: '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/rom': Input/output error
root@wanka-GL703VM:~# echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/rom
0
```

When running `sudo dmesg | grep 0000:01:00.0` I get this:

```
wanka@wanka-GL703VM:~$ sudo dmesg | grep 0000:01:00.0
0.351823] pci 0000:01:00.0: [10de:1c20] type 00 class 0x030000
0.351848] pcі 0000:01:00.0: reg Ox10: [mem 0xde000000-0xdeffffff]
351871] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg Ox14: [mem Oхс0000000-0xcfffffff 64bit pref]
0.351894] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
0.351910] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x24: [io 0xe000-0xe07f]
0.351926] pci 0000:01:00.0; reg 0x30; [mem 0xdf000000-0xdf07ffff pref]
0.351949] pci 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
0.351955] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 1: assigned to efifb
0.351964] pci 0000:01:00.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
0.352049] pci 0000:01:00.0: 32.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, lmited by 2.5 GT/s PCIe x16 link at 0000:00:01.0 (capable of 126.016 Gb/s with 8.0 GT/s PCIe x16 link)
0.406844] pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
0.406850] pcі 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
0.406853] pcі 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem, locks=none
0.436702] pci 0000:01:00.1: Do power state depends on 0000:01:00.0
0.437105] pcі 0000:01:00.0: Adding to iommu group 1
2.394959] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
2.395024] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GP106 (136000a1)
2.482920] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 86.06.5f.00.05
2.484104] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: pmu: firmware unavailable
484691] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 6144 MiB GDDR5
2.497685] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 6144 MiB
2.497689] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 536870912 MiB
2.497692] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: BIT table 'A' not found
2.497695] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: BIT table 'L' not found
2.497698] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
2.497701] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.1
2.497704] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 00: 02803f76 04400020
2.497707] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 01: 02012f62 00020010
2.497710] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 02: 04824f86 04400010
2.497713] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 03: 04824f82 00020010
2.497716] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 02: 00010261
2.497718] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 03: 00020347
2.497721] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 04: 01000446
2.498021] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies
3.060963] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM; allocated 1920x1080 fb: 0x200000, bo 000000008113958b
3.551598] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: [drm] fb0: nouveaudrmfb frame buffer device
3.573956] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
3.573971] nouveau 0000:01:00.0; DRM; Disabling PCI power management to avoid bug
101.446749] snd_hda_intel 0000:01;00.1; bound 0000:01:00.0 (ops nv50_audio_component_bind_ops [nouveau])
686.859505] nouveau 0000:01:00.0; Invalid PCI ROM header signature: expecting oxaa55, got 0xffff
```

For context this is my hardware and software:

```
Processor: 7th gen Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ Processor
GPU: GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile
GPU Driver: X.org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)
```